# Contagem crescente decimal em nodejs

Tags: node.js

Estou a desenvolver um sistema, onde tenho que começar a contagem no 1.00 e ir por ali alem até um numero que estará escolhido no banco de dados.

O que pretendo saber é como posso fazer um contador crescente em nodejs, que suba de centésima em centésima ou seja 1,01 ; 1,02 etc... Até chegar no valor que eu desejo.

Contudo quanto maior for subindo o numero, mais depressa ele subirá, depois passará a subir cada vez mais depressa.

OBS: Não envolve milésimas de segundo nem nada relacionado a tempo mas sim, quanto maior for o número subindo ainda mais depressa ele vai continuar a subir.

Como poderei fazer isto em nodejs?

Obrigado.

Comment: Consegues descrever o modelo de incrementação com uma fórmula matemática? Ou descrever 1.01 > 1.02 > ... e depois? 1.03 ou 1.035, ou 1.04?

Comment: Gonçalo viste a minha pergunta? ^

Comment: Desculpa Sérgio, tive sem acesso á internet só hoje pode ver. O que pretendo não tem qualquer "formula" matematica, mas o mais semelhante que se pareça é por exemplo: de 1.01 até 2, demorar 30 segundos. de 2 até 3 demorar 25 segundos... Mas a contagem ser de 1.01 em 0.01 de 0.01

Comment: Ok, é algo assim que procuras? https://jsfiddle.net/85rLudgo/

Comment: Gonçalo, viste o meu jsFiddle? ^

Comment: Sim é isso mesmo! Desculpa a demora, mas estava a espera que um amigo meu analisa-se. É ele que me está a ajudar no projeto.

Comment: Se houver uma resposta que resolva o problema podes marcar como aceite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que eu vou dizer é provavelmente um comentário irrelevante...

O número 0.01 é traiçoeiro: não tem representação exacta em notação binária normal (dízima infinita periódica).
Experimenta algo como `for(var i = 1; i < 1000; i+=0.01){imprimir i}` e os erros acumulados são facilmente visíveis.

Vai daí, para evitar os erros acumulados, propunha:

- contagem com inteiros;
- número da sequência calculado a partir da contagem: contagem/100

```
for (var i = min; i < max; i++) {
      var seq = i/100;
      ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode implementar um "for" no teu código onde a condição incremental é uma sequencia modificada pelo valor atual da variável a ser incrementada, da seguinte forma:

```
var min_inicial = 1.0    

for(var min = 1.0; min < max; min += (min - min_inicial + 0.01)) 
{
   //Garante que min não será superior a max, 
   //  considerando o método de incremento utilizado.
   if(min > max) min = max;

   //Código que utilizará a sequencia aqui...
}
```

Onde:
- "max" é o valor limite obtido do banco de dados.
- a cada iteração do "for" a variável min receberá seu próprio valor, decrecido do valor inicial e somado 0.01.

Desta forma a variável receberia os seguintes valores após n interações:

n é 1 => min = 1.0 + (1.0 - 1.0 + 0.01) => min = 1.01

n é 2 => min = 1.01 + (1.01 - 1.0 + 0.01) => min = 1.03

n é 3 => min = 1.03 + (1.03 - 1.0 + 0.01) => min = 1.07

É necessário ter cuidado com este algoritmo pois o valor final de min pode ser superior a max, neste caso é necessário igualar eles ao final do loop, conforme descreve o código.

Não é a implementação mais bonita, mas acho que resolve teu problema.